# How to catch FailedLoginException in Picketbox/Undertow on Wildfly 8 to apply CORS

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, authentication, wildfly-8

With the help of a ContainerResponseFilter I am able to apply CORS headers to all outgoing Responses, and with an ExceptionMapper I can do the same on all Errors and Exceptions, *except* for any authentication related Exceptions that Picketbox/Undertow is supposed to throw in Wildfly.

My ExceptionMapper *never* catches it no matter what I try, and as a result, the frontend can't read the 401 status since the response doesn't have the CORS headers appended (the XHR HTTP status code just becomes 0).

I am using [this](https://github.com/m9aertner/PBKDF2) PBKDF2 setup to authenticate against a MySQL database, and at first I thought that maybe since the authentication was run in a separate module it wasn't being caught by my application, but even after moving all the authentication code into my own application I have the same problem.

This is the log entry I get when trying to authenticate with the wrong password (I get a very similar one when I simply don't send any credentials at all):

> 2014-11-29 16:11:08,053 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-4) PBOX000224: End getAppConfigurationEntry(PBKDF2DatabaseDomain), AuthInfo: AppConfigurationEntry[]:
>   [0]
>   LoginModule Class: com.example.myapplication.security.SaltedDatabaseServerLoginModule
>   ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: required
>   Options:
>   name=dsJndiName, value=java:/user
>   name=principalsQuery, value=SELECT `Hash` FROM `account` WHERE ID=?
>   name=rolesQuery, value=SELECT `Role`, 'Roles' FROM account WHERE `account`.`ID`=?
>
> 2014-11-29 16:11:08,053 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-4) PBOX000236: Begin initialize method
>   2014-11-29 16:11:08,053 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-4) PBOX000262: Module options [dsJndiName: java:/user, principalsQuery: SELECT `Hash` FROM `account` WHERE ID=?, rolesQuery: SELECT `Role`, 'Roles' FROM account WHERE `account`.`ID`=?, suspendResume: true]
>   2014-11-29 16:11:08,053 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-4) PBOX000240: Begin login method
>   2014-11-29 16:11:08,053 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-4) PBOX000263: Executing query SELECT `Hash` FROM `account` WHERE ID=? with username 1@2.se
>   2014-11-29 16:11:08,062 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-4) PBOX000283: Bad password for username 1@2.com
>   2014-11-29 16:11:08,062 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-4) PBOX000244: Begin abort method
>   2014-11-29 16:11:08,062 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-4) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required
>       at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:284) [picketbox-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:408) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]
>       at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]
>       at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]
>       at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verifyCredential(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:111)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verify(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:82)
>       at io.undertow.security.impl.BasicAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(BasicAuthenticationMechanism.java:110) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:281) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:298) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:268) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:131) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:106) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:99) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:54) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:27) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]

And this is my ExceptionMapper class (currently set to catch all Throwables in a vain attempt to make it work):

```
@Provider
public class NotAuthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>{

@Override
public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {
    Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers, allow, content-length, date, last-modified");
    return response;
}
```

What can I do to catch these authentication Exceptions and thus append CORS to them?

Comment: I am using Keycloak and have the same issue. It seems to be that the application, including webfilters, jax-rs filters etc never get into play in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I managed to figure out that you can add custom headers to all *non-error* outgoing responses on Wildfly by modifying the configuration file (standalone.xml). This solved the problem for me:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <https-listener name="default" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="cors-origin"/>
                <filter-ref name="cors-methods"/>
                <filter-ref name="cors-headers"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="cors-origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="your-domain-here.com"/>
            <response-header name="cors-methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"/>
            <response-header name="cors-headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="origin, content-type, accept, authorization, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers, allow, content-length, date, last-modified, if-modified-since"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

Edit: Turns out Wildfly isn't appending the CORS headers to unauthorized responses, but when it runs into 500-errors it very neatly ignores them. Any idea on how to fix this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="*"`  Alas... `*` is no longer accepted as a value by popular browsers. You must fill in the actual origin name here... making this solution no longer very useful.

Comment: @StijndeWitt: I've updated the solution with "your-domain-here.com" instead of the wildcard. However, if you put your actual domain there, I fail to see why the solution would not be very useful in that case? It should do exactly the same thing, only not for domains other than your own. From a security point of view you should never use the wildcard there anyway.

Comment: Yes it's a reasonable solution if you have only one domain. As soon as you have more than one domain you are in trouble though. In the end I had to write my own Undertow filter to get it done, so yeah I think it's an issue in Wildfly in that sense that it's *much* too hard to set the CORS headers in the correct way on the Wildfly stack.

Comment: Oh and the Unauthorized responses,the only way I found to handle e.g. 403 response is to set an error page in the web.xml. Maybe there is a better way with jax-rs but I already spent significant time on it and could not find anything so yeah. All in all it's a pretty messy solution wih filters in Jax, in Undertow, custom error pages etc. Not very nice imnsho. But I'm getting off-topic  :)