# Servlet response filter for non 2xx http code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, wildfly

I want to add some headers to http response from my server. I need to headers to be added regardless of the code(2xx, 4xx, 5xx) that returns the app. I tried to implement `javax.servlet.Filter` with `@WebFilter` annotation and `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter` with `@Provider` annotation, but methods `doFilter` and `filter` called only when application returns 200 http status code. Is it possible to use filters for non 2xx responses?

I'm using Wildfly 8.2.0 as app server, but I think it's not important

**EDIT**

I think I should give more information about my problem. My application is REST-service implemented by Resteasy. Also I have configured security policy for authorization by using Wildlfy security subsystem. I need to response from REST-service always contains CORS headers for every request from frontend, even client doesn't pass authorization check. But when response code is 401, filter methods don't called, even if I use `DispatcherType.ERROR`, how suggest **@Steve C**.
So, I don't return any status codes, all codes returns server (as say **@ACV**). Maybe this is cause, that filters don't work for my case.

**EDIT II**

I found partial answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203830/how-to-catch-failedloginexception-in-picketbox-undertow-on-wildfly-8-to-apply-co). It's possible to add headers to all non-error (non 5xx) responses by configuring undertow subsystem at Wildfly standalone.xml

Comment: I suspect that you will need to implement some kind of JASPIC wrapper to catch that 401. In the past I have noticed that most (but not all) Java EE implementations do not pass authentication related requests (including those directed to `j_security_check` through the filter chain at all. Alternatively an undertow valve may do the trick

Comment: Thank you, it's possible catch 401 by using filters at undertow subsystem. I have updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the [DispatcherType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/DispatcherType.html) in your @WebFilter declaration:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns={...}, dispatcherTypes={ERROR, REQUEST, ...})
public class ...
```

Comment: I tested this and it does not actually work (WildFly 10). I wonder why it is accepted. I have the same scenario as the OP and I added all values from `DispatcherType` to the `dispatcherTypes` array and still the filter does **not** fire for 401s. I wonder why JBoss implemented it this way. But they are certified so it must be according to spec.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a standard servlet filter. By the way. 404 comes from the server not from your application. Also 500. You can return these codes by yourself, in that case, the filter should work. Also, another solution would be to set the headers before any request. But this won't save you from the 404 problem.
[How to set servlet filters](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html)

Comment: But 401 comes from the security subsystem... so how would you implement it there? Standard filter does **not** fire on 401 from the container.

Comment: @StijndeWitt, try this guide as suggested above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203830/how-to-catch-failedloginexception-in-picketbox-undertow-on-wildfly-8-to-apply-co

Comment: Read my comments... This answer does not answer the question. The linked tutorial is generic for servlet filters (but they don't fire, that's the very problem) and the SO question you refer to offers only half of a solution. You can get away with it as long as you have a static config for the header with only a single domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to capture errors through an error-page declaration in your web.xml:

```
<!--
The error-page element contains a mapping between an error code
or exception type to the path of a resource in the web application
-->
<error-page>

    <!--
    The error-code contains an HTTP error code, ex: 404
    -->
    <error-code></error-code>

    <!--
    The location element contains the location of the resource in the web
    application relative to the root of the web application. The value of
    the location must have a leading `/'.
    -->
    <location>/my.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

... and then code my.jsp to process the response in case of error (I've always done exception processing with JSPs; I don't know if a servlet URI would work as well).

The only drawback is that you'll have to include explicitly an  node for each HTTP error you want to process.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13712/web_xml.htm#WBAPP537